# How can I have access to the files in a Azure Static Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

In my Azure subscription an external company deployed from there BitBucket an application that I commissioned. The company ran out of business and I want to get all the files in the Static Web App to continue developing the application.

The `Sku` is `Free`. There is not `Kudu` to explore the content nor a FTP. I found same posts on Stackoverflow but all of them are dated.

[image]

Is there a way to access the Static Web App and/or copy the files?

Answer (score 2):

Check the below steps to access the files of `Azure Static Web App`.

We can check the `branch/source` details in Azure Portal at 2 places.

***Way 1 :***

In `Azure Portal` => Your `Static Web App` => In `Overview` pane

We can find a `Source` and `Deployment history` options.

[image]

We can see the `Source` as Git.
Irrespective of the option we select to deploy the Application (`GitHub`/`Devops`/`BitBucket`), all the source files are saved in the `GitHub Repository`.
If we click on the URL, it will be redirected to the deployed files.

***Way 2 :***

In `Static App` =>  Under `Settings` tab, click on `Environments`.
We can see the Production Branch details. Click on the branch URL, it will be redirected to the Source files.

[image]

> There is not `Kudu` to explore the content nor a FTP.

`KUDU` option is available only for `Azure Windows App Service`.

Refer  [drware Tutorial](https://www.drware.com/tutorial-publish-azure-static-web-apps-with-bitbucket/) to `Publish Azure Static Web Apps with Bitbucket`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the BitBucket and I don't have the option to check the branch.

Comment: Have you checked the `Source` and `Deployment history` option from portal ?